# How to design and store dates by weekly monthly yearly for items in SQL database using Windows Forms and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I try to write an evidence maintenance software that will keep maintenance interventions over some equipment.

Example:

- Equipment 1 with id:313
- Equipment 2 with id: 314

I have to store & read maintenance evidence for these two pieces of equipment.

There are three types of maintenance: weekly, monthly, yearly.

For 313, I have done maintenance as type: weekly on 11/20/2017 and I need to know when I made last maintenance and when is the next one, and for 314 is monthly type  like 11/21/2017  to 12/21/2017.

So there are 3 variables

```
DateTime LastMaintenace = some date;
DateTime NextMaintenance;

if (maintenancetype = daily)
{
     NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.AddDays(7);

     // Here I need to store next maintenance as last maintenance 
     // and show event for the next maintenance date;
}
```

I was thinking for three variables:

1. First time when maintenance was done for 313
2. Last time when maintenance was done for 313
3. Next time when maintenance needs to be done for 313

But I'm lost, I don't know how to think this, I have 1000 thoughts.

I'm using EF, SQL, Windows Forms.

Comment: `SQL` is a **query language** - not a database system. Many things however **are** vendor- and database-specific, so please add a tag for your **actual, concrete RDBMS** you're using - `mysql`, `postgresql`, `db2`, `oracle`, `sql-server` or whatever you might be using ....

Comment: i`m using sql server

Comment: Anyone could help me??